# Removing nodes of polygon inside other polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, geometry, nodes

I have a shapefile with numerous errors of this type (see img. 1), i.e. polygons inside other polygons consisting of a few nodes.

[image]

I have tried repairing the geometries with the tool and it doesn't work.
The geometry checker (see img. 2) crashes due to the size of the file, probably.

Am I getting the geometry checker settings wrong?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried selecting by area and deleting the selection?

Comment: Have you tried "Fix geometries" processing tool?

Comment: Or v.clean? ..,-

Comment: if the correct polygon have always more vertice you may try an expression  like :  num_points(  $geometry )< 5 that will select all polygon with 4 or less vertices (adapt the value to your case) then erase the selected polygon